# MongoDb Titlecase in Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In my collection i need to change the firstname and lastname to be in Titlecase.since its in nested array i couldn't proceed.

```
db.users.find()
  {
    "users" : {
        "assigned" :[
                       {
                        "firstName" : "naveen",
                        "lastName" : "bala",
                        },
                        {
                        "firstName" : "SHAJU",
                        "lastName" : "HARI",
                        },
                        {
                        "firstName" : "PADMANESH",
                        "lastName" : "NC",
                        }
                     ]
                }
            }
```

I need the result to be like

```
{
   "firstName" : "Padmanesh",
    "lastName" : "Nc",
}
```

Tried this code below

```
 function titleCase(str) {
        return str && str.toLowerCase().split(/\s/).map(function(word) {
            return word && word.replace(word[0], word[0].toUpperCase());
        }).join(' ');
    }
    
    
db.users.find().forEach(function(doc){
    db.users.updateOne(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": { "firstName": titleCase(doc.firstName) } }
    );
});
```

Comment: If you want to do it in JS then try this `let string = "ABCD"; console.log(string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase());`

Comment: I want it to be done in angular 8. there i can't able to handle it .since its in  ng-select  in bind label. That's y thought of changing in mongo collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way is to use updateMany(). You can see how the titleCase operators work here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/xdePfeBvIQ1

https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html

This should do it for you, you can match using the first arg if needed.

Please double check the user schema is correct in your question. If its not this will need to be tweaked. It expects each user doc contains a `users` object with an `assigned` property.

```
db.users.updateMany({}, [{
  $set: {
    "users.assigned": {
      $map: {
        input: "$users.assigned",
        in: {
          firstName: {
            $concat:[
              {$toUpper: {$substrCP: ["$$this.firstName", 0, 1]}},
              {$toLower: {$substrCP: ["$$this.firstName", 1, {$strLenCP: "$$this.firstName"}]}},
            ]
          },
          lastName: {
            $concat:[
              {$toUpper: {$substrCP: ["$$this.lastName", 0, 1]}},
              {$toLower: {$substrCP: ["$$this.lastName", 1, {$strLenCP: "$$this.lastName"}]}},
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks. this is it .this works correctly . I just mentioned above is rough schema. but it worked as expected in my schema .

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, to do it on the mongo shell :

```
var titleCase = function (str) {
  return (
    str &&
    str
      .toLowerCase()
      .split(/\s/)
      .map(function (word) {
        return word && word.replace(word[0], word[0].toUpperCase());
      })
      .join(" ")
  );
};

db.users.find().forEach(function (doc) {
  var a = doc.users.assigned;

  a.forEach(function (person, index) {
    var setop = `users.assigned.` + index + `.firstName`;
    var uppered = titleCase(person.firstName);
    db.users.updateOne(
      { _id: doc._id, "users.assigned.firstName": person.firstName },
      { $set: { [setop]: uppered } }
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes . thanks . this one also working fine for me .This will be useful for me in other collections.